# scout:import appends numbers to elasticsearch index name

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I'm using the matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch package and when I run `php artisan scout:import` on a model the index that gets created has a timestamp appended to it.

For example my config and searchableAs() method on the model returns 'groups' however the index that is created is 'groups_1632322111'. The appended timestamp updates on subsequent imports.

Is there a way to prevent the timestamp from being added?

Here is my config:

```
<?php

return [
    'host' => env('ELASTICSEARCH_HOST'),
    'indices' => [
        'mappings' => [
            'default' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                        'type' => 'keyword',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'events' => [
                'properties' => [
                   'id' => [
                     'type' => 'keyword'
                   ]
                ]
            ],
            'groups' => [
                'properties' => [
                    'id' => [
                      'type' => 'keyword'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'settings' => [
            'default' => [
                'number_of_shards' => 1,
                'number_of_replicas' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Check if it also creates an alias. There's good reasons why the index name is created with the timestamp appended but there's no reason why it can't be aliased back to `groups`

Comment: @apokryfos thank you! I indeed discovered that the timestamped version is being aliased to 'groups' on import.